# Different ways of determining event's type - what design pattern to use?

Tags: java, design-patterns, wrapper

In my application there are two ways *events* can be received - either from the background handled by the `BackgroundEventListener` class or read in as a line from file handled by the `FromFileEventListener` class. Let's assume they both implement the following interface:

```
public interface EventListener<E> {
  void mousePressed(E mouseEvent);
  void mouseReleased(E mouseEvent);
  void mouseClicked(E mouseEvent);
}
```

The `BackgroundEventListener` class:

```
public class BackgroundEventListener implements EventListener<MouseEvent> {
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler;
  public BackgroundEventListener() {
    eventHandler = new BackgroundEventHandler();
  }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(mouseEvent, "mousePressed");
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(mouseEvent, "mouseReleased");
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(mouseEvent, "mouseClicked");
  }
}
```

We can see that the `BackgroundEventListener` class passes in the type of the event directly depending on which of the methods was called.

`EventHandler` interface and implementations:

```
public interface EventHandler<E> {
  void handleEvent(E event, String type);
}
```

Background:

```
public class BackgroundEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(MouseEvent event, String type) {
//        TODO handle event coming from background
  }
}
```

From file:

```
public class FromFileEventHandler implements EventHandler<String> {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(String event, String type) {
//        TODO handle event coming from background
  }
}
```

**Here comes my question**. In the background case the event type has to explicitly be passed as an extra argument. However, when an event is read from file the information about the type of the event is present **in the event itself**. Therefore, the `FromFileEventListener` class would need to look something like this:

```
public class FromFileEventListener implements EventListener<String> {
  EventHandler<String> eventHandler;
  public FromFileEventListener() {
    eventHandler = new FromFileEventHandler();
  }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(String event) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(event, Utils.getTypeOutOfEvent(event));
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(String event) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(event, Utils.getTypeOutOfEvent(event));
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(String event) {
    eventHandler.handleEvent(event, Utils.getTypeOutOfEvent(event));
  }
}
```

This results in the event being passed in as the first argument and the second argument being the type which needs to be extracted beforehand, for example using a public static method `getTypeOutOfEvent(String event)` of class `Utils` - an obviously unnecessary duplication of data and splitting event processing between different classes.

What would be the elegant solution to that problem? What design pattern should I use? (One way I thought of was to create an `EventWrapper` which I could use to wrap either a `String event` or a `MouseEvent event, String type` pair)

Comment: The background events do not contain their own type? The file events are not objects but Strings?

Comment: Yes, let's assume the background events don't know their type. And as for event coming from file I assumed they would be just lines read from a file, so Strings.

Comment: Can you transform the data of MouseEvent to a String that conforms to the "FromFile" event Strings format?

Comment: Could do but then the String would be further processed so ideally would avoid processing twice

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that your goal is to have only one common EventHandler to avoid duplicate code?

Comment: No, I'm ok with having various EventHandlers - events from file that come in as String will be handled differently from background events that come in as MouseEvent. But I don't like doing a bit of processing in the EventListener (getting the event type out) and the rest in the EventHandler. All event processing should (conceptually) be done in one class which could be treated as a black box, be unit tested, etc.

Comment: I think you are wrong there. I think the parsing of an event may well be done in the listener, creating an event *object*, and the handler should be responsible only for *handling* the event, that is, responding to whatever the event contains. The listener is what knows the medium it reads from, and therefore the format of what it reads. The event handler should be medium-independent.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is place for [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. You have two ways of receiving events, so there should be two strategies how to handle it.